# Get substring after a pattern in C#

Tags: c#

Looking to get the substring after the last comma or the last pipe.  So say I have a string that could be either:  "pipe|delimited|string" or "comma,delimited,string", the result should be "string" in both cases.

I'm looking at C#'s substring on a lastindexof, but I don't know how to do it for both pipes and commas.  Something like this:  str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('|' or ',')).   Any ideas?

Comment: did you mean the second example to be "comma,delimited,string"?

Comment: What if your data contains pipes or commas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a nice function for that.

```
str.LastIndexOfAny(new []{',','|'});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which splits a string on one or more delimeters into an array, and then select the last item in the array. Since it takes multiple characters, you can just include both the pipe and the comma characters when you call it:

```
input.Split('|', ',').Last();  // Splits on both characters and returns the last "chunk"
```

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var input = "string|delimited|by|pipes";
    Console.WriteLine(input.Split('|', ',').Last());

    input = "string,delimited,by,commas";
    Console.WriteLine(input.Split('|', ',').Last());

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Split()` method should do the trick. The only thing about it is that it will use both delimiters at the same time, so, for example, `string,delimited|sequence` will be turned into an array of strings that looks like `{"string", "delimited", "sequence"}`. There are a few examples for what you want at [Microsoft: How to Parse Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split). This one might be most pertinent.

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

string text = "one\ttwo three:four,five six seven";
System.Console.WriteLine($"Original text: '{text}'");

string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
System.Console.WriteLine($"{words.Length} words in text:");

foreach (var word in words)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"<{word}>");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:
("pipe|delimited|string").Split('|').Last()